# RoR, Sizzle Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /sv/priser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, sizzle

**The error**

```
   jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:1464 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /sv/priser
        at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:1464)
        at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:2121)
        at Sizzle.select (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:2542)
        at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:865)
        at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:2788)
        at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:2905)
        at jQuery (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:76)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (kontakt:50)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:4733)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.self-977e28a4e7fded7698789e394a585c6339d54c0ad1537f498a40d2800098a521.js?body=1:4545)
```

Getting this error when clicking on a to_link tag in RoR v.5.2 (Ruby v2.5)
The link works, and takes me to the targeted html.erb file. I can't find any solution that has worked.

**The tag** *the error occurs for all tags like this, this one is just an example.*

```
<%= link_to 'Prices', en_prices_path, :class => "page-scroll", id: 'prices' %>
```

**My routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  namespace :en do
    get 'index' => 'pages#index', as: 'home'
    get 'prices' => 'pages#prices'
    get 'about' => 'pages#about'
    get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'
  end

  namespace :sv do
    root 'pages#index', as: 'home'
    get 'priser' => 'pages#priser'
    get 'om' => 'pages#om'
    get 'kontakt' => 'pages#kontakt'
  end
  get '*path' => redirect('/sv')
end
```

Its noteworthy to mention that the link exists in a partial _nav file that that is being rendered into an index or contact.html.erb file amongst others, that is then being rendered into the application.html.erb file.

I hear talk about jquery complaining about bad selectors, which makes me believe the paths (for example sv_priser_path) the router gives me is bad (it gives me /sv/priser). Can i edit them perhaps? Would that stop the error from happening? I tried parsing them with

```
$($.parseHTML(sv_priser_path)[1]
```

but that i didnt get that to work either. Didnt get a replace script to work either to remove the slash.